# Android is not matching closest size drawable when I use getResources().getIdentifier()

Tags: java, android

Here is my code:

```
    int id;
    String[] imageList = {"pic_1_480dpi", "pic_2_480dpi",
                          "pic_3_480dpi", "pic_4_480dpi",
                          "pic_5_480dpi", "pic_6_480dpi"};

    // Get reference to image on screen
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_View_2);
    // Increment image list counter
    counter++;
    if (counter > 5) counter = 0;
    id = getResources().getIdentifier(imageList[counter], "drawable", getPackageName());
    image.setImageResource(id);
```

I only get the images in drawable-hdpi folder even though it is running on a 10.1 tablet. I have same-named images in the drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi folders but they do not get selected for display. Is there a better (i.e. more correct) way to look for drawable IDs when selecting from a string array.

Comment: The 10.1 tablet has a xhdpi screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen size doesn't indicate the dpi. Which device is it? The dpi is a combination of the screen physical size and resolution.
I guess you're already familiar with the following link, if not, I suggest reading:

[Android: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the link. What I am missing here is Android system's built-in facility for choosing the closest match from the various Drawable folders (MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI, XXHDPI). The getResources().getIdentfier() process doesn't appear to look for the closest Drawable match for the target unit's screen size. Thanks.

Comment: Again, are you sure the device you're checking has xhdpi? The fact that it is a 10.1'' device doesn't mean the dpi is such. It can even be ldpi if the screen resolution is low.

Comment: Lior...thanks for staying with me on this. I just ran a DisplayMetrics() on the tablet: {density=1.0,width=1280,height=752,scaledDensity=1.0,xdpi=149.82489,ydpi=150.51852}

Comment: what was the answer ?